# Readiness Check Error during extension installation

Tags: magento-2.1, php, extensions

When I install any extension in Magento 2 the Readiness Check shows my following errors:

1. (Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is .)
2. (PHP Settings check & missing PHP extensions) but doesn't show which settings/extensions were required.

I install Magento 2.1.11 and php verison 7.0.27

Comment: What's the output if you create a simple php page with `phpinfo();` as output? Does it show the right PHP version as well as PHP extensions required for Magento 2? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: yes it shows correct version of php